# How can I save and replicate NFC tag data on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc

iPhone has a sensor to read and transmit data via NFC.

So my question is:
Is there any iPhone software that can **save and replicate** the data contained in NFC tags?

(like NFC badge, NFC transport card and more...)

Comment: You can read payload from one NFC and write that payload to another NFC (that isn’t locked). When you look at the API, it should all be pretty self-explanatory. That assumes that they are compatible (e.g., different NFCs have different capacities, so you can’t write a payload that exceeds the technical capacity/limitations of the destination NFC).

Comment: It depends on the typeof the card. A simple storing tag can be replicated, but a transport card is using e.g. counters to avoid replication = multiple use.